# How to calculate time worked past midnight in excel to show proper value not a negative

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using a formula that calculates time worked `=IF(((D5-C5)+(F5-E5))*24>8,8,((D5-C5)+(F5-E5))*24)` which works great for time *before* midnight; but I need to modify it to display time worked past midnight. The issue is that when you put a value after midnight the calculation returns a negative value see image 2 row 5 In: 1600 out:2000 in:2030 out: 0100 returns a -15.50 value.

I have seen some options posted but I am unsure of how to integrate into this formula:

.[image: Timesheet]
 [timesheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1XuA.jpg)

Comment: How do you represent midnight? `0:00`?

Comment: Use the function =DATEDIFF. It'll work past midnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(((IF(D5>=C5,D5,D5+1)-C5)+(IF(F5>=E5,F5,F5+1)-E5))*24>8,8,((IF(D5>=C5,D5,D5+1)-C5)+(IF(F5>=E5,F5,F5+1)-E5))*24)
```

Basicaly if end time is lower than start time, add 1 day to end time.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem, but now a new issue has arisen with my formula to calculate OT after 8 hours. I am using =IF(((D5-C5)+(F5-E5))*24>8,((D5-C5)+(F5-E5))*24-8,0)

Comment: You just replace D5 with IF(D5>=C5,D5,D5+1) and F5 with IF(F5>=E5,F5,F5+1)

Comment: I do not believe I am doing this right as I am returning strange results. How should the complete formula look?

Comment: try with
`=IF(((IF(D5>=C5,D5,D5+1)-C5)+(IF(F5>=E5,F5,F5+1)-E5))*24>8,((IF(D5>=C5,D5,D5+1)-C5)+(IF(F5>=E5,F5,F5+1)-E5))*24-8, 0)`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, I see now where I went wrong I was mixing up the arguments.